# Поэтапная форма отправки

Tags: php, ajax, форма, xhr

Всем доброго времени суток!
Пишу поэтапную форму отправки с логикой: 1 этап -> запись в куку -> второй этап -> запись в куку -> подтверждение -> отправка в БД записей из куки.
С этим все отлично, но с редактированием предыдущего этапа возникла проблема. После клика по **`.return-step-one`** количество XHR-запросов удваивается, сначала 2, потом 4, 8, etc.
Вот JS:

```
$(".addinfo").each(function(){
    console.log(this);
    $(".send-one", this).on("click", function(e){
        var name = jQuery(this).data('name') || 0;
        var family = jQuery(this).data('family') || 0;

        $("#info-block").load("/ajaxController", {
            action:"add", 
            module:"tosteptwo",
            name:$("#name").val(),
            family:$("#family").val(),
        });
    });

    $(".send-two", this).on("click", function(e){
        var phone = jQuery(this).data('phone') || 0;
        var email = jQuery(this).data('email') || 0;

        $("#info-block").load("/ajaxController", {
            action:"add", 
            module:"done",
            phone:$("#phone").val(),
            email:$("#email").val(),
        });
    });

    $(".return-step-one", this).on("click", function(e){
        $("#info-block").load("/ajaxController", {
            action:"edit", 
            module:"tostepone",
        });
    });
});
```

PHP в зависимости от прилетевших запросов возвращает tpl в **#info-block** в единичном количестве, но запросы растут. Подскажите, как решить проблему.

Comment: для чего Вам `.on("click"...` в `each`?

Comment: Вы многократно навешиваете одинаковые обработчики события `click` на одни и те же элементы

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать JS, так подсказали на форумах

Comment: @Igor Можно более подробно? Не совсем понимаю, как это получается

Comment: я тоже пока не знаю - в вопросе недостаточно информации и кода. Вот, например, у Вас есть вызов `console.log(this);`. Сколько раз в консоли появляются новые объекты?

Comment: @Igor один раз появляется при загрузке всей страницы div.addinfo.container. Скажите, что еще нужно скинуть? Дополню вопрос

Comment: @ЮрийБондаренко что содержится в `tpl`, который вы загружаете в `$("#info-block")` ? указанный js находится в главной странице или в загружаемом `tpl` ?

Comment: @Alex в tpl содержится форма и кнопки с навешанными событиями. JS туда не включен, располагается на основной странице

Comment: "кнопки с навешанными событиями" - вот этот кусок покажите

Comment: @Igor `<button class="send-one btn btn-success btn-block" type="button">Далее</button>
`. На остальных этапах меняется класс: `send-two`, `return-step-one`

Comment: спасибо. А где "навешанные события"? Как, например, `send-one` получает обработчик клика?

Comment: @Igor , если я правильно понимаю, то вот: `$(".send-one", this).on("click"...`

Comment: Вы говорите, что этот код выполняется один раз (во время загрузки страницы). `$(".send-one", this).on("click",...` навешивает обработчик на элемент[ы], существующие на странице в этот момент. Вопрос остается: как навешиваются обработчики на подгружаемые элементы? Подозреваю, что повторным вызовом приведенного или подобного кода.

Comment: @Igor получается, что именно так. Но как сделать по другому?

Comment: Сначала надо найти вызовы "этого или подобного" кода и убрать их. А клики назначать делегированием `$(document).on("click", ".send-one", function(e) { ...`, которое покроет существующие элементы и те, которые будут созданы потом .

Comment: `$(".addinfo").on("click", ".send-one", function(e) { ...` и не нужен цикл `$(".addinfo").each(`